# How Can I Limit an .OpenDataSource in Word Mail Merge to Only 1 Record Using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Word 2013, SQL Server 2014
I have a Word Mail Merge template that was originally created for a licensing application that uses an .ini file and an Excel file to generate one certificate from a dataset of many.

I want to make the Word Template work on it's own. I was able to wire up a .udl file to make a connection to the database but it gives me all the tables, then I pick one, then it gives me a document for each row in that table when I only need one.

How can I limit/filter the document that comes from the template to only use a specific table and a specific row (license_id) I request?

```
Sub AutoNew()

'THIS RETURNS ALL ROWS AFTER I PICK A TABLE
With ThisDocument.MailMerge
    .OpenDataSource Name:="C:\Users\or0146575\Desktop\xxx.udl"
    .Execute
End With

End Sub
```

I would wire up the below code to only return 1 row if I knew how.

```
Dim sql As String

sql = "SELECT full_name, BigLicenseType, LicNosDisplay, expiration_date FROM OpCerts WHERE person_id= 30012"
```

Comment: You must have more than one record with that ID. You can always start your query with `Select Top 1` to only bring back the first record.

Comment: Thanks dbmitch, but I still couldn't get the T-SQL wired up to the .OpenDataSource. I changed directions for a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a totally different route and hope it doesn't detract from my points.

Using a datasource file like a .udl or .odc was bringing back all records AND required selecting the table at runtime and I couldn't get the sql to work.

I decided to make the connection with good old ADODB (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library in Tools > References) and assign the values to the mailmerge fields or DOCVARIABLE fields or Bookmarks, which ever will work. No sense in using mailmerge for just one record. I hope this helps someone.

```
Sub AutoNew()

Dim strWhat As String

strWhat = InputBox("Enter License ID", "OpCert Wall Certificate")


Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DWS_Licenses;Data Source=WPDHSCLR16C"

conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT full_name, BigLicenseType, LicNosDisplay, expiration_date FROM OpCerts WHERE person_id=" & CInt(strWhat)


Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = cmd.Execute() 'Execute stored procedure.

'THIS WILL BE CHANGED TO BOOKMARK(S) PROBABLY IF DOCVARIABLES DOESN'T WORK
ActiveDocument.Variables("expiration_date").Value = rs(3)
'PUT full_name, BigLicenseType, LicNosDisplay TAGS HERE

rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing

Set cmd = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```